# ¿Como manejar rutas de una aplicación php en un servidor real?

Tags: php, rutas

Hola estoy intentando subir mi primera aplicacion web a un servidor compartido. El caso es que localmente funciona bien pero al subirlo al servidor me encuentro con errores 404 y 500. Estuve cambiando unas cuantas cosas y al parecer es problemas con las rutas. Para trabajar localmente eh usado rutas absolutas como por ejemplo

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/panel/bd/dashboard.php';
```

pero al usar esta ruta la aplicacion web que desarrolle me muestra un error 404. Pero si cambio la ruta a

```
include '../panel/bd/dashboard.php';
```

entonces ya no se muestra el error 404. Entonces no se si tendria que cambiar todo a rutas relativas o hay alguna manera de solucionar esto sin liarme mucho. Algun consejo?

Comment: Revisa tu .htaccess tanto local como en el servidor a ver si hay algo que difiera y pueda estar afectando, si es que los usas. Luego recuerda que `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` apunta a la raíz de tu dominio, por lo tanto si lo has puesto en una carpeta es normal que no encuentre las cosas

Comment: en realidad no eh creado nigun archivo .htacces aun. Ni local ni en servidor

Comment: pues mira si es que lo has puesto en una carpeta dentro de tu **public_html** del compartido... si es un cpanel debes subirlo a `/home/cuenta/public_html` pero si lo has subido a `/home/cuenta/public_html/carpeta` entonces no va a encontrar bien el `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` pues apunta a `/home/cuenta/public_html`

Comment: Creo que entiendo voy a mirar